# Refreshing training data for supervised learning - how to?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

We have a classifier for web pages. The classifier model was built with train data from some 2 years ago. We've noticed the model's performance keeps deteriorating, and we assume its due to properties of web pages changing over time (mainly used words and terminology, but also topology, html tags, etc.).

How would you approach this problem? do we simply re-build the entire train data and re-learn a new model? Is there a shortcut? Are there some common practices or papers on how to do it? Note that we are pretty hooked on the supervised learning approach where the system admins train a classifier, evaluate its performance on a test set and then install the classifier in the "production" system.

Hope this isn't too vague...

Comment: If you model is not good anymore I would suggest to build a new one. What was the algorithm used to build the model ?

Comment: hi @ihadanny,  have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of factors that may come into consideration, the major ones being the state of the classifier and the data.

If you do not require any new inputs as a result of changing web protocols, then you may be able to retrain your existing classifier on fresh data.

If the classifier has not been designed to be retrained on new data, it may be difficult to salvage the old model.  Likewise, if the inputs or outputs have changed, it may also be easier to build a new classifier.

I don't know what classifier you are using, or the means to retrain or process your data, so I can't provide a direct answer to the issue you are facing, or if there are any shortcuts to the problem.  It really comes down to how accessible your classifier is and the cost of maintaining it.

As stated in your question above, it would be recommended that the new classifier be tested and compared to confirm that it meets the requirements before applying it to the production environment.

Comment: Its basically a set of home-brew binary classifiers - for each cateogry we compute a TFIDF-style score, and then predict the probability the sample belongs to that category. We then simply pick the highest probability.

Comment: Thanks ihadanny.  I think it boils down to whether there are additional rules/protocols that need to be embedded into the model itself, and whether it is simple/cost-effective to retrain the existing model.  If these are no problem to your classifier (and hopefully they are not!), then it shouldn't be too much of an issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a standard, off the shelf classifier, there likely isn't a way to update the parameters for new data (it depends on exactly what you're using). Rebuilding from scratch is probably the fastest way. If you go down this route, consider including the old data plus some new data, possibly weighting newer data higher (weighted loss functions can do this). Keeping the old data around will probably minimise the amount of new data you need to create.

If you want to be able to continuously update your model in light of new data (i.e. if this will be a recurring problem), consider switching to a classifier that supports online learning out of the box. The obvious choice would be one of the Passive Agressive family of learning methods: [MIRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_Infused_Relaxed_Algorithm) is pretty good (it's basically an online SVM).

Comment: Thanks. I understand that MIRA still requires supervised learning. The samples might come one-by-one instead of in a big dataset, but you still need to tag them before feeding them to the machine. Methodologically speaking, do you think its better than using the first approach you mentioned - i.e. setting a time-interval (Say every half a year), in which we update the big data set with new data, and re-train?

Comment: It removes the need to worry about weighting of past signals, but you're a lot less likely to find a standard library implementation. Both are reasonable options I think